# Magento 2.2.3 Minicart missing proceed to checkout text

Tags: template, onepage-checkout, phtml, mini-cart, magento2.2.3

I would like you help on this I have been reading and reading and cant find an answer. 
Magento 2.2.3 with a templatemonster theme

This is my minicart.phtml, and the problem is the proceeed to checkout button text is missing on home page, however if I click on edit cart, I can see the text working. In the browser console I get $(...).find(...).dropdownDialog is not a function error.

But if I'm in www.site.com/checkout/cart/configure/etc on the product page I get no error at all. I have tried changing the template files with the core files and it screws up everything else.

```
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>
<div class="rd-navbar-cart-wrap">
<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <div class="rd-navbar-cart-fixed">
        <a class="action showcart rd-navbar-cart-toggle" href="" data-rd-navbar-toggle=".rd-navbar-cart" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
             <span class="text"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('My Cart') ?></span>
            <strong class="counter qty empty"
                    data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <strong class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                <strong class="counter-label">
                    <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                    <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- /ko -->
                </strong>
            </strong>
        </a>
    </div>

    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'" class="rd-navbar-cart">
            <div class="block block-minicart empty">
           <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                </div>
                <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>

</div>
```

Ok, so, I have been checking both minicart.phtml files (core and template). If I add

```
data-role="dropdownDialog"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
            "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
            "triggerTarget":".showcart",
            "timeout": "2000",
            "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
            "closeOnEscape": true,
            "triggerClass":"active",
            "parentClass":"active",
            "buttons":[]}}'>
```

Under

```
<div class="block block-minicart empty"
```

The error in the console goes away, but the minicart does not work in any page, so I'm thinking there has to be something bad in the template, I can post the content.html file too, if you think the error might be there instead. Thank you!

**SOLVED**

Answer (score 0):

All that was needeed was to remove 
    click: closeMinicart() 
from content.html

Got no more console errors, and everything is working as it should. Hope this helps someone with this problem.